# Very annoying issue with Firefox Quantum 66.0 : scrolling sites with arrows keys not working properly

Tags: keyboard, xubuntu, firefox, scrolling

After an auto-upgrade Firefox quantum to 66.0, scrolling sites with arrows keys (<kbd>up</kbd> / <kbd>down</kbd>) not working properly, scroll jumps to a paragraph of the webpage and select texts box and so on. I can't scroll smoothly.
How do I fix that?

OS: Xubuntu 16.04.6

Comment: Very annoying is the right sentence. Preferences > Use Autoscrolling is the option. Thanks for asking this, Vladimir.

Answer (score 3):

You can enable/disable smooth scrolling & go back to the old behavior in *Preferences* > Type "scrolling" in "find in preferences" box.
There you may find the desired Scrolling options.
[image: Image instance]

Comment: @h k That's it, solved my problem, thks. (very annoying bug)

Comment: @vladi If you find this answer useful, please consider ["accepting" it](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) (by clicking the tick (✓) next to it) to indicate you've found a working solution and also so that others may more easily find it in the future.

Comment: If just toggling an option in Preferences solves the problem, then it's most likely **not a bug**.

Comment: @pomsky I accept the answer, but where is the tick to click??I can't find it :)

Comment: @vladimirpavloski Did you ask the question using a different account? You need to login using the account you asked the question first.

Comment: @pomsky I'll check which account I used to ask this question.